# Google Analytics shows traffic source to Mongo DB items as 'google / organic'

Tags: google-analytics, mongodb

One of our clients' sites uses Mongo DB for a section of the site. I've set up a regex filter to only show specific items from this database:

^/path1/path2/(.*)/item/(.*)$

The regex works as planned, however almost all the items are shown as having the source/medium as 'google / organic'. I'm fairly certain that Google can't index the DB, and even more certain that nobody is arriving directly at these items from the SERP as googling sections of each item's content comes up with nothing.

Does anybody have any idea why the traffic isn't shown as 'direct'?

Thanks

Comment: Can you find the URL of the landing page in behavior of Analytics? Visit the landing pages and see if there is an analytics tracker in them. My guess is that Google is sending traffic to pages that is using the content from path1/path2 and those pages have the tracker on it.

Comment: Traffic source is for the landing page.   My guess is that those are not landing pages at all.   The attribution is coming from some other page they use first.

Answer (score 1):

No idea why it is doing that, but use the Google Analytics Debugger (a Chrome Extension) that shows all of the information that is carried across to GA as a page loads.

This is a good article on GA debugging:

https://www.optimizesmart.com/geek-guide-google-analytics-debugging-troubleshooting/

If it were me, I would:

1) Install the plugin in Chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en

2) Turn on the developer console in Chrome and make sure the plugin is on

3) Paste one of the MongoDB URLs into Chrome and see what is passed in the console view

4) If the referrer is organic, you'll know (although I don't know why it would be) at least you can create a rule to filter out the spurious data.

Good luck!